# is there a more performant way to get the value of a property of a class from the propertyName inside a loop using reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```cs
public class Product
{
    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public string Copy;
}

 

public void setCopyProperty(List<product> products, string propertyName)
{
    foreach(var product in products)
    {
        var propertyValue = //refection
        product.Copy = propertyValue;
    }
}
```

I am iterating over a list of products and trying to set Copy property with the value of a property that i have to get dynamically.
Is there a way to avoid reflection for each iteration ?

Comment: Do you have control over the class code?

Comment: Yes I have control over the class code

Comment: `performant` and `reflection` - these are words that don't usually go together well.

Comment: performant use of reflection is a curious game. the only winning move is not to play.

Comment: Think of an alternative, like using a dictionary or using a switch expression. It is difficult to give you an advice, since we do not know why you are doing this. Which problem are you trying to solve. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Cache `propertyInfo` and reuse it later.

Comment: If you don't know the class you're using and the properties you want **at compile time**, then there is no way around reflection. If it's not fast enough, you'll need to rethink your data structures.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question..

..for cases where I've wanted to be able to enumerate class properties in a non reflective way I've stored the data in a dictionary:

```
public class X{

  private Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  public string Y { 
    get{ return (string)_values[nameof(Y)]; }
    set{ _values[nameof(Y)] = value; }
  }

  public int Z { 
    get{ return (int)_values[nameof(Z)]; }
    set{ _values[nameof(Z)] = value; }
  }
}
```

The dictionary can be enumerated, the key is the property name etc. If there are particular performance considerations such as you don't want to hit dictionary hashing/casting for millions of gets, and have infrequent sets, you can use a normal backing variable as well as the dictionary; update them both but only get the variable

```
public class X{

  private Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  private string _y;
  public string Y { 
    get{ return _y; }
    set{ _values[nameof(Y)] = _y = value; }
  }

  private int _z;
  public int Z { 
    get{ return _z; }
    set{ _values[nameof(Z)] = _z = value; }
  }
}
```